# continual vs. continuous

Tags: vocabulary

In the following sentence can "continual" be replaced with "continuous"?

" Many of  sportspeople spend their retirement in a continual battle against depression, alcohol, or drugs."

Personally, I think when this word carries a "sense of annoyance", no replacement can be done. However, when it means "continuing without interruption" it can be replaced with "continuous".

Comment: Did you look up both words?  https://www.google.com/search?q=continual+vs+continuous

Comment: Indeed. Many sites are brought up with that search that are specifically talking about the same thing, unless you're asking something else.

Comment: @stangdon: Yes. And I've studied some of those explanations but since they both overlap each other, at least in one sense, I just wanted to know how a native speaker of English looks at it. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @M.N: I agree that it is not easy.  If it makes you feel any better, even native speakers of English get these words mixed up!

Comment: Stangdon's right - most native speakers tend to use them interchangeably.  It's not quite considered "correct", but it's very common.

Comment: FWIW - The way I learned to keep them straight was by extending the final consonant sound.  "S" can be turned into a long unbroken hiss - _continuoussssssssssss_ is uninterrupted  "Continual" ends in an "l" sound, which is much easier to repeat over and over than it is to draw out: _Continual-l-l-l-l-l_ repeats in an interrupted, staccato fashion. Hope that helps someone.

Answer (score 3):

I would say that you should not  substitute *continuous* for *continual* there.

*Continual* can mean "again and again" (repetition) or "uninterrupted", but *continuous* means only "uninterrupted".

Even though the typical expression is "constant battle", the battle against depression, alcohol, or drugs is marked by periods of progress and backsliding, so it's not continuous, but continual in that sense.

But it really depends on what you want to convey. Is it a "never-ending" battle?   An "unrelenting" battle?   A battle that is never won?